# To display a Text Field on selection of a particular pick list value

Tags: apex, javascript, formula, jquery

My requirement is suppose a pick list field is there like "Bill Shipment to", and it's values are 'SHIPPER', 'RECIPIENT' & 'THIRD PARTY', then if i select third party then a text field will be auto populate beside this picklist field to fill the "Account no of Third Party". How to achieve this? Please help me..

Comment: In visualforce page?..use rendered condition ....based on that you can show and hide your "text"

Comment: Where u have taken the Object name in which we have to perform the task.